# passing an array from model to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my model, I am getting all emails in an array. I want to show this array of emails in controller, not in view.

Here my model is:

```
     public function cron_job(){
     $this->db->select('email');
     $this->db->from('wc_buyer');
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query; 
  }
```

and the controller is:

```
    public function cron_job(){
    $this->load->model('home/Home_model');
    $data['a'] = $this->Home_model->cron_job();
}
```

How can I show this print this array of emails in variable in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
     public function cron_job(){
             $this->db->select('email');
             $this->db->from('wc_buyer');
             $query = $this->db->get();
             $result = array();
             foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                $result[] = $row;
             }
             return $result; 
        }

 public function cron_job(){
    $this->load->model('home/Home_model');
    $data['a'] = $this->Home_model->cron_job();
    print_r($data['a']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You echo your email in controller use `result_array()` as

```
$email=$this->Home_model->cron_job();// get data from model
foreach ($email->result_array() as $row)// fetch data form query 
{
        echo $row['email'];
}
```

Comment: Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$data = $this->Home_model->cron_job();
print_r($data); // To print array
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter provide a method `result_array()` which return the resulting query into array, in your case, do it this way.

In your model

```
public function cron_job(){
     $this->db->select('email');
     $this->db->from('wc_buyer');
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

In your Controller,

```
public function cron_job(){
    $this->load->model('home/Home_model');
    $data['a'] = $this->Home_model->cron_job();
    $this->load->view('path/to/the/file', $data);
}
```

In your view,

```
<?php foreach ($a as $key => $value) : ?>
  <?php echo $value['your_table_field']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```